# I can't find where the error occurred when using vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

When I run this code, I can get the Debug Assertion Failed error.

"Expression: vector erase iterator outside range"

I can't find where the error occurred.

```
for (int i = 0; i < comb.size(); i++) {
        if (couple.size() != 0 && couple.size() == mate * 2) {
            vector<int>::iterator iter = couple.begin();
            int rad = rand() % couple.size();
            rad = (rad % 2 == 0 ? rad : rad + 1);
            iter += rad;
            iter = couple.erase(iter);
            iter = couple.erase(iter);
        }
        couple.push_back(comb[i]);
        printf("%d ", comb[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `printf()` instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: As far as I know, printf() is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Let's assume `couple.size() == 6`.
- Let's assume `rad == 5`.
- Then `rad` will be transformed to 6.
- Then you will call erase() on an iterator past the end of the array. Which is illegal.

I'm going to guess that you should have done:

```
rad = (rad % 2 == 0 ? rad : rad - 1);
```

But it's hard to say since you never explained what you're trying to accomplish.